# Facebook Ads Leads to RingCentral "Create Webinar Registrant"

Tags: api, zapier, ringcentral

How can I have a Facebook Ads Lead > Zapier > to RingCentral and Create Webinar Registrant?

The meetings and webinar functions of RingCentral are fully powered by Zoom, essentially RingCentral meetings and webinars ARE Zoom meetings and webinars with different branding.

It is completely possible to have a Facebook Ads Lead > Zapier > to ZOOM and Create Webinar Registrant.

So How can we do the same with RingCentral meetings and webinars?